# Is there a way to have two exchange or two queue for the single consumer one for testing message and another for production message?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a requirement where while deploying the rabbitmq consumer component, if there is any message on the queue then this consumer component should not consume the message immediately once deployment is done.

After the deployment there is sanity test on this component, once sanity test is done then only this consumer component should start consuming the message from the queue.

I have made autostart = "false" on the consumer component so that consumer will not consume the message once deployment is done.
After sanity test is done then I start the container listener using rest call.

The problem is sanity test also posting the message on the same queue. Sanit test is failing as the message posted by sanity test is waiting in the queue due to autostart = "false".

Is there a way while the production message still waiting on the queue but sanity test message can be consumed ?

```java
@RabbitListener(id = LISTENER_ID,
            bindings = @QueueBinding(exchange = @Exchange(value = "${listener.exchange}", type = "topic"),
                    value = @Queue(value = "${listener.queue}", durable = "true"), key = "${listener.routingKey}"),
            containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory",  autoStartup = "false" )
    public void receiveMessage(@Valid @Payload RequestMessage requestMessage,
            @Headers Map<String, Object> requestHeaders) {

            //some code

            }
```

Comment: Generally, there would be different rabbitmq instances maintained - eg: one for testing & prod..so, you would get 2 different exchanges. If you want to maintain same exchange for dev & prod & 2 different queues, that also possible, but not recommended. Anyways, the strategy is to use spring profiles, so you can maintain different config for dev & prod

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use 2 queues and 2 listeners (or change the listener to only listen on the sanity queue and then add the production queue to the listener container).

Comment: May I know how I can do this please?  - 1. change the listener to only listen on the sanity queue and then add the production queue to the listener container,. 2.Is that possible using the above one method, can i configure two queue, making one queue autostart = false and another queue autostart = true ?

Comment: `@RabbitListener` is `@Repeatable` so the simplest solution is to add 2 `@RabbitListener`s to the method (one with `autoStartup="false"`). You can do it programmatically using `addQueueNames()` on the container, but that is a bit more involved, especially if you use the default `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`; it's a lot easier with a `DirectMessageListenerContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a single Queue listen to 2 exchanges.
It is also possible to have two queues listening to a single exchange.
**RabbitMQ is all about bindings**, all you need to do is proper binding. See the snippet below (Spring AMQP).

```
package com.savk.workout.spring.rabbitmqconversendreceivefanoutproducer;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AmqpConfig {

    private final String PREFIX = "savk-sndandrcv-fanout";
    private final String RK = PREFIX + "-" + "rk";
    private final String EXCHANGE = PREFIX + "-" + "exchange";
    private final String QUEUE = System.getenv("INSTANCE");    //PREFIX + "-" + "queue";

    @Bean
    public Exchange exchange()  {
        return ExchangeBuilder.fanoutExchange(EXCHANGE).autoDelete().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue()    {
        return QueueBuilder.nonDurable(QUEUE).autoDelete().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue2()    {
        return QueueBuilder.nonDurable(QUEUE).autoDelete().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding1(Exchange exchange)    {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange).with(RK).noargs();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding2(Exchange exchange)    {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue2()).to(exchange).with(RK).noargs();
    }

}
```